# New wordpress dev site setup but all inks point to homepage

Tags: wordpress, development-environment, staging

I've got a live Wordpress site that is working fine. Time for a few updates, so the guy hosting this site for us has created a new subdirectory, 'newdev', and copied the live site into it.

He said he's updated the database, and in my Dashboard-->Settings-->General, the WordPress Address (URL) has been updated to http://newdev.thecyclery.net.au (while the live site URL is http://thecyclery.net.au.

I find that I can open the homepage of the dev site OK, but if I click any links, it takes me to that page on the live site. E.g, I'm on http://newdev.thecyclery.net.au, then click 'Ride' and it takes me to http://thecyclery.net.au/ride

If I manually enter the URL for sub-pages (e.g. http://newdev.thecyclery.net.au/ride) it directs back to the DEV homepage.

I really need to be able to see my dev pages so I know that the work I'm doing is working and displaying correctly... Any suggestions?

Thanks, I hope I've provided enough info!!
Jon

Comment: have you changed the home url in database?

Comment: you have to change the home and base url in option table.

Comment: Thanks @HarshSanghani... I don't have access to the database - the host manages that end of things. He says he's updated the database, but is this pretty clearly what the problem is to you? I can double check with him if needed...

Comment: ya its home and base url problem only in the database, Please confirm that and let me know.